# Elasticsearch scoped aggregation not desired results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query but the aggregation doesn't seem to be acting on top of the query.

The query returns 3 results there are 10 items in the aggregation. Looks like the aggregation is acting on top of all queried results. 
Basically, how do I get the aggregation to take the given query as the input?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "geo_distance": {
              "coordinates": [
                -79.3931,
                43.6709
              ],
              "distance": "15km"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "user.type": "2"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "user.shoes": "314"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "dedup": {
      "terms": { "field": "user.id" }
      "aggs": {
        "dedup_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: 2.3 but I think I figured it out. I'll answer this question below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, I was expecting the aggregation to act on the paginated results given by the query. And that's incorrect.

The aggregation takes as input "all results" of the query, not just the paginated one.